# Shortcut for open in terminal option of windows 11

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11

How to assign a keyboard shortcut to open in terminal option in windows 11 which we get when we right click in a folder? Actually I want the terminal's path same as directory's path which we get when we right click and choose open in terminal option

Comment: I want to know the answer to this too, but this really should be on superuser not stackoverflow

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318467/1498178

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this should be on another stackexchange site (probably superuser), but unfortunately it is too old now to migrate.

Answer (score 2):

Just came back to this, the best method I have is press the menu key if your keyboard has it (same as right clicking) or press SHIFT-F10.  Then press T for terminal (Up until a few versions ago terminal didn't have a shortcut, I raised an issue ( https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/13061 ) and it got fixed in July.

Still not as fool proof as the old ALT - F - R method or as universal  ( it depends if you have other shortcuts that have T has their accelerator key ).

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for this. I was using ALT - F - R to open powershell on Windows 10. For Win11 the closest thing to shortcut i could give is

- press F4 in directory
- CTRL + A to select all path
- write cmd or wt and hit enter.

It will open cmd or terminal with directory's path.